# how to add additional sort if string starts with date?

Tags: c#, linq

I'd like to do an additional sort by date where the value starts with a date("01/01/2000 description"). is it possible?

```
       var result = await
   (from book in db.booksTable
          where book.IdCategory == request.bookCategory
          select new 
          {
                 Author = book.Author ?? "unknown",
                 Opinions = (from opinion in db.opinionsTable
                 join critic in db.criticTable on opinion.IdCritic equals critic.Id into c
                 from critic in c.DefaultIfEmpty()
                 orderby critic.order, HERE additional orderby
                 where book.id == opinion.IdBook && critic.order != null
                 select new
                 {
                        Value = opinion.Text ?? "empty",
                        critic.Topic
                 }).ToList()    
          }
   ).ToListAsync();

   my Value:
   "example"
   "Sample description1"
   "01/12/2021 other description"
   "Sample description2"
   "05/01/2021 other description"
   "09/01/2000 other description"
```

Comment: "The value" being `opinion.Text`? Ideally that date would be stored in a separate column. If it can't, you'll have to try and parse the first 10 characters of each value as DateTime.

Comment: yes, value = opinion.text.

Comment: Use String.Split(' ', 1) and not the first X characters, in case date don't include leading zeroes.

Comment: can it be done in the in my query ?

Comment: What LINQ are you using: LINQ to Objects / SQL / EF 6.x / EF Core 2.0 / 2.1 / 3.x / 5.x / 6.x? What database provider?

Comment: If you are using EF Core >= 3.0 with MS SQL Server, you can use `orderby critic.order, (EF.Functions.IsDate(opinion.Text.Substring(0, 10)) ? (DateTime)(object)opinion.Text.Substring(0, 10) : DateTime.MinValue)`

Answer (score 1):

Implement a static method that compares two strings:

```cs
public static int JerryCompare(string left, string right)
```

Within that method, try to parse the date.

```cs
string potentialDateLeft = left.Split(' ', 1)[0];
if (DateTime.TryParse(potentialDate, out DateTime leftDateTime)) { ... }
```

Then, depending on your logic (do you want items with dates first? last?), compare the dates and titles and return -1 if "left" comes before "right", 0 if they're equal, and 1 if "left" comes after "right".

Then, sort your list using

```
myListOfTitles.Sort(JerryCompare);
```

Where `myListOfTitles` is the list you've gotten from your query above.